# String manipulation weirdness when incrementing trailing digit

Tags: python, regex, string

I got this code:

```
myString = 'blabla123_01_version6688_01_01Long_stringWithNumbers'
versionSplit = re.findall(r'-?\d+|[a-zA-Z!@#$%^&*()_+.,<>{}]+|\W+?', myString)

for i in reversed(versionSplit):
    id = versionSplit.index(i)
    if i.isdigit():
        digit = '%0'+str(len(i))+'d'
        i = int(i) + 1
        i = digit % i
        versionSplit[id]=str(i)
        break

final = ''
myString = final.join(versionSplit)
print myString
```

Which suppose to increase ONLY the last digit from the string given. But if you run that code you will see that if there is the same digit in the string as the last one it will increase it one after the other if you keep running the script. Can anyone help me find out why?

Thank you in advance for any help

Comment: `id` is a reserved python word, change it for something else (that's not related to your question by the way)

Comment: The line `id = versionSplit.index(i)` finds the first occurence, not the last one as you intend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is the use of the `list.index()` function on line 5. This returns the index of the *first* occurrence of a value in a list, from left to right, but the code is iterating over the *reversed* list (right to left). There are lots of ways to straighten this out, but here's one that makes the fewest changes to your existing code: Iterate over indices in reverse (avoids reversing the list).

```
for idx in range(len(versionSplit)-1, -1, -1):
    i = versionSplit[idx]
    if chunk.isdigit():
        digit = '%0'+str(len(i))+'d'
        i = int(i) + 1
        i = digit % i
        versionSplit[idx]=str(i)
        break
```

Comment: `for idx in reversed(range(len(versionSplit))):`

Answer (score 8):

Is there a reason why you aren't doing something like this instead:

```
prefix, version = re.match(r"(.*[^\d]+)([\d]+)$", myString).groups()
newstring = prefix + str(int(version)+1).rjust(len(version), '0')
```

Notes:

- This will actually "carry over" the version numbers properly: ("09" -> "10") and ("99" -> "100")
- This regex assumes at least one non-numeric character before the final version substring at the end. If this is not matched, it will throw an `AttributeError`. You could restructure it to throw a more suitable or specific exception (e.g. if `re.match(...)` returns `None`; see comments below for more info).

Adjust accordingly.

Comment: Not tested, but I suspect this will do unhelpful things if the string doesn't end in a digit?

Comment: That's the typical solution that looks beyond what is being answered. I like it. +1

Comment: @dbr The list is *supposed* to end in a digit. An exception or an error would need to be thrown if not so, I think.

Comment: @heltonbiker exactly, the OP specified that the string ends with version digits. If this is not the case, the re.match will return a `NoneType` which doesnt have a `.groups()` and will in turn throw an `AttributeError` (this can of course be restructured to throw a more specific exception), which can then be wrapped in a try/catch exception block (since then it **is** an *exceptional* case)

Comment: I mention this because the `if i.isdigit():` check in the original code implies the trailing number may be optional (if so, checking if `re.match` returns None is better than catching the AttributeError!)

Comment: @dbr yes that is why I mentioned in my comment above that it could be restructured to throw a more specific or "correct" exception :). Also I went more by the requirements in OP's description in terms of what is an error and what is not; Regardless of his code, OP's description implies that the trailing number is not optional; And I prefer taking the stricter/failing early choice if there is ambiguity.

Comment: Thank you all, just to clarify i am after the last digit in the string, doesnt necessary has to end with one. I have adjusted my question. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

```
myString = 'blabla123_01_version6688_01_01veryLong_stringWithNumbers01'
versionSplit = re.findall(r'-?\d+|[^\-\d]+', myString)

for i in xrange(len(versionSplit) - 1, -1, -1):
    s = versionSplit[i]
    if s.isdigit():
        n = int(s) + 1
        versionSplit[i] = "%0*d" % (len(s), n)
        break

myString = ''.join(versionSplit)
print myString
```

Notes:

- It is silly to use the `.index()` method to try to find the string.  Just use a decrementing index to try each part of `versionSplit`.  This was where your problem was, as commented above by @David Robinson.
- Don't use `id` as a variable name; you are covering up the built-in function `id()`.
- This code is using the `*` in a format template, which will accept an integer and set the width.
- I simplified the pattern: either you are matching a digit (with optional leading minus sign) or else you are matching non-digits.
- I tested this and it seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

First, three notes:

1. `id` is a reserved python word;
2. For joining, a more pythonic idiom is `''.join()`, using a literal empty string
3. `reversed()` returns an iterator, not a list. That's why I use `list(reversed())`, in order to do `rev.index(i)` later.

Corrected code:

```
import re

myString = 'blabla123_01_version6688_01_01veryLong_stringWithNumbers01'
print myString
versionSplit = re.findall(r'-?\d+|[a-zA-Z!@#$%^&*()_+.,<>{}]+|\W+?', myString)

rev = list(reversed(versionSplit))  # create a reversed list to work with from now on

for i in rev:
    idd = rev.index(i)
    if i.isdigit():
        digit = '%0'+str(len(i))+'d'
        i = int(i) + 1
        i = digit % i
        rev[idd]=str(i)
        break

myString = ''.join(reversed(rev))  # reverse again only just before joining
print myString
```